# Localization inside shortcode not working

Tags: shortcode, xgettext

I use a shortcode that retrieves the url of woocommerce products and builds a link:

```
function woo_url_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );
    $html = '';
    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ) {
        $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        $html = $_product->get_permalink();
    }
    $text = 'Some text';
        return '<p class="woo-booking"><a href="'.$html.'">'.$text.'</a></p>';
}
```

Works fine. But now I need the text translated like this:

```
esc_html_e( 'Some text', 'generatepress-child' );
```

So, the code would be:

```
function woo_url_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );
    $html = '';
    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ) {
        $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        $html = $_product->get_permalink();
    }
        return '<p class="woo-booking"><a href="'.$html.'">'.esc_html_e( 'Some text', 'generatepress-child' ).'</a></p>';
}
```

Language files are there and working. But not with this shortcode. The string is translated but appears at the top of the page and is repeated several times. What exactly am I missing, and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`esc_html_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/) displays (`echo`) the output, hence it appears at the wrong place. So you should instead use [`esc_html__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/) which returns the translated string.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch for the help!